# Anime where the youngest of eight brothers has the power of seven swords

Tags: story-identification, anime

The main character has **seven  older brothers**. He is injured in an accident, and in order to save him the powers of his brothers are transferred to him. These powers happened to be **seven different  swords**. The eldest of the brothers is the strongest, and has wings everytime he uses his sword or something. Another one of the seven swords is a broadsword. I forgot the others.

Comment: Can you remember whether the story was set in modern times, or in the distant past? Did the brothers live in a city, or in a rural area? What colour was the main character's hair?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236682/anime-about-seven-swords-main-characters-sword-has-a-wind-attack-another-uses?

Comment: @Valorum, just noting that we told him to post it as its own question on that question. ^_^

Comment: The setting of the story is in rural area or specifically  in a village. It's on a distant  past, I guess. For the hair color of the main character, I can't remember. Oh, there was a scene where the MC and a comrade fought with someone and he used the broad sword; as he swung his sword it cut through the boulder where his friend was hiding and his friend's hair got cut off.

Comment: I think the title of this anime is "Beet the Vandel Buster".